# external stylesheet from a github release does not load

Tags: css, github

I created a .js and .css file from a project and added them to a github release

https://github.com/natearn/react-vim-tips/releases

I then attempted to add the code directly to a webpage using an external script and stylesheet (linking directly to the files in the release).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/natearn/react-vim-tips/releases/download/1.0.0/VimTips.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://github.com/natearn/react-vim-tips/releases/download/1.0.0/VimTips.css">
```

For context, the script creates a global function which renders a react component, which I execute elsewhere on the page.

The network requests for the files succeed after a redirect (so 302 then 200), the javascript loads and runs, but the css rules do not get added to the page.

When I copy the stylesheet and fetch it locally, it works. So I believe the problem is in the mechanism of delivery from the CDN.

Can someone tell me what might be happening here, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that GitHub repos are **different** from web hosting services. You are correct that the issue is related to how the `.css` file is being served (or rather, in your case, not being served at all). There are a few options:

1) Create a **gh-pages** branch and reference your `stylesheet` from there i.e. https://natearn.github.io/react-vim-tips/stylesheets/VimTips.css. This should actually serve your CSS properly.

2) Use [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) to generate a proper CDN link to your `VimTips.css` file. I gave this a shot and have a working example at this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bcjjdo?file=index.js. Here's the CDN link I used: https://cdn.rawgit.com/natearn/react-vim-tips/32b5ee66/stylesheets/VimTips.css

The crucial point is that either of these strategies will serve your CSS with the correct Content-Type headers, enabling them to actually load as CSS in your page. Referencing the link to downloads from your release simply prompts a download of the binary data for your CSS file, which will not work. Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

<del>Use the raw version of the file from your repo,</del>

<del>I have this css file from an old `Hello World` repo,
using https://github.com/mcarpenterjr/Hello_World/blob/master/style.css you get the file in the repository.</del>

<del>Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mcarpenterjr/Hello_World/master/style.css 
you get the raw file, which is what you're looking for. To get this simply click the raw button to the upper right of the file contents on a file's page from the repo.</del>

<del>I suppose you could also swap `https://github.com` for `https://raw.githubusercontent.com` and drop `blob` from the address.</del>

**Just use this** -> https://rawgit.com/

Works flawlessly.

Comment: Okay, I tried this and it also has the wrong content-type (text/plain), so unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry didn't test before answering, I did, however, update my answer.